# simplexml_load_file() alternatives in drupal to fetch API data

Tags: feeds

Hello I just really want to know how can I fetch data from a API Link and store the data in database? In custom PHP I used `simplexml_load_file()` to fetch the data from API. I created the following page in custom PHP .
[example.com](http://example.com/browsestore.php).
I want to do the same functionalities in my drupal site.
Should I copy the same code from the above site in my drupal module. Will it work? I dont want to use external module like 
**aggregator**
 or **feeds**
This may be a basic question for some user but for me it is very crucial to understand this.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Since the question is about code, you should show the code you are talking about. Differently, we cannot answer your question in any useful way.

Comment: Why don't you want to use feed or another module? As drupal is php there should be no reason why you could not just use the code from the other site.